# How to obtain exact error on cognito failure

Tags: go, amazon-cognito

I was wondering where can I find the exact error that cognito would send when it would have an internal error. For example, I list the users for a pool and cognito returns an internal error, where could I find the exact error that gets returned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Cognito API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) you can find a list of errors that are being returned from the different API calls, here is the error list for [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) for example:

> **InternalErrorException**
> This exception is thrown when Amazon Cognito encounters an internal error.
> HTTP Status Code: 500

> **InvalidParameterException**
> This exception is thrown when the Amazon Cognito service encounters an invalid parameter.
> HTTP Status Code: 400

> **NotAuthorizedException**
> This exception is thrown when a user isn't authorized.
> HTTP Status Code: 400

> **ResourceNotFoundException**
> This exception is thrown when the Amazon Cognito service can't find the requested resource.
> HTTP Status Code: 400

> **TooManyRequestsException**
> This exception is thrown when the user has made too many requests for a given operation.
> HTTP Status Code: 400

Since you have tagged "Go": If you are using the Go SDK you get an awserr.Error and you can use its Code and Message methods to learn more about the error that has been returned. See the [Go SDK Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.ListUsers) for more information.